# absolute path not working in gatsby with images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Here is the image:

`<img src="src/img/image.svg" alt="" />`

The folder structure is like so:

```
src
 -img
 -components
 ...etc
```

Yet the image shows nothing and I get a 404 error in the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Gatsby looks for static assets in the `static` folder at the root of your project](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-images-fonts-files/#using-the-code-classlanguage-textstaticcode-folder), so make sure your image is located at `static/src/img/image.svg` if you want your example image to work, and you don't want to use the Webpack module system.

Comment: I remember using this now! Although i just made a static folder in the root dir and made an `img` folder to house all the images and then just referenced it like so `/img/image.svg`

Comment: I am using url for images like - https://sampleurl-forbes.svg but image is not loading. Can you help me with this?